# Why I can not use ./geth --testnet --fast --cache=1024 --jitvm for geth 1.4.7?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, jitvm

I tried two times. Each time block count is for mainnet and there is no any chaindata for testnet

Comment: This is working fine for me on Geth 1.5.0. `~/.ethereum/testnet/chaindata` is getting populated as expected.

Comment: Still not working in geth 1.4.9